# get the last word (uppercase)

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm writing a code to print the last word in the string in uppercase and remove special characters or numbers if there is any, my code for now just print the last word how can I make it uppercase a remove any special characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char line[80] = "abc dfg, egh.";
    int i = 0, j;
    char *last_word;

    while (line[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (line[i] <= 32 && line[i + 1] > 32)
            last_word = &line[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (last_word && last_word[i] > 32)
    {
        write(1, &last_word[i], 1);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: use [`toupper`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html)

Comment: Copy it to a new array, skipping any "special" characters and using `toupper` for the characters you actually copy.

Comment: On another couple of notes, please try to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), and use [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification).

Comment: Loot at `strrchr()` to find the last space in the string (or just use strrchr() with `'\0'` to find the end and work backward to find the last word). You can use `isalpha()` to check for only `[A-Za-z]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ctype.h library to use toupper function.
I checked string character by  character is an alphabetic character or not thanks to ASCII values the code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

int main()
{
    char line[80] = "abc dfg, egh.";
    int i = 0, j;
    char *last_word;

    while (line[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (line[i] <= 32 && line[i + 1] > 32)
            last_word = &line[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (last_word && last_word[i] > 32)
    {
        if ((last_word[i] > 64 && last_word[i] <91) || (last_word[i]> 96 && last_word[i] < 123 ))
        printf("%c", toupper(last_word[i]));
        
        i++;
    }
}
```